# Existence of the limit of a bounded analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity, analytic-functions

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $U\subset\mathbb{C}
$ be open. If we have an analytic function $f:U\setminus \left\{ 0\right\}
\rightarrow X$ such that $\underset{x\in U\setminus \left\{ 0\right\} }{\sup 
}\left\Vert f\left( x\right) \right\Vert <\infty ,$ can we say that the
limit $\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\lim }f\left( x\right) $ exists. Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried adapting a proof from the case where $X=\mathbb C$?

Comment: Not yet,  but I think that if X is finite dimensional then the limit exists